# How to create a factory configuration for a DS component from specific bundle version?

Tags: osgi, declarative-services

I have a DS based component with servicefactory annotation property and ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE.
I'm using ConfigAdmin to create instances of such service.

```
@Component(enabled = true, servicefactory = true,
    service = ServiceFactoryTest.class,
    configurationPid = "servicefactory1",
    configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
public class AnComponentServiceFactoryForTest extends
    AbstractComponentWithCompendium implements ServiceFactoryTest {
```

In order to create an instance of the service I'm using the following method of CM Service in an extender bundle:

```
configuration = getConfigurationAdminService()
                    .createFactoryConfiguration(
                            "servicefactory1", null);
configuration.update(new Hashtable<>(getPropertiesMap()));
```

Suppose that I have multiple versions of the bundle that contains that component installed at same time. How can I create a configuration for a specific version ?

I know the existence of the locator parameter, I used to set it as null just because I don't know which value to use. How to know the value each of those DS component are expecting?

Comment: Have your tried to use http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationAdmin.html#createFactoryConfiguration(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) ? And pass a bundle location.

Comment: @wbinglee, I saw that location parameter but I couldn't figure out which value to use when configurations are being created inside an extender bundle in the name of a contributor bundle for a component service in another bundle.